# Dynamically add HTML5 Videos or just pause it?

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

Load wise and speed wise, i have a one page website, and i have a slider, inside each slider there is a html video. I'm wondering what is the best practise for videos considering website speed and load..

Example.. i have

```
<div id="slider>
  <div class="slide-1 active">
     <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-2">
     <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-3">
     <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-4">
     <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-5">
     <video></video>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-6">
     <video></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Slider is not set on autoplay, and only one video is added when slider the is active if slider is not active no video is there.. And other videos are not added right away so it would not delay the load..

My question is on switching slider and playing the video. Should i remove the previous video when i switch slider? or should i just pause it? rather than removing and adding the video again when user navigates to different slider? Can anyone advise me what is the best way to do this considering speed wise and load wise? I want to keep everything as smooth as possible.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are streaming the videos then just pausing should be fine - the client (browser) will only request enough 'chunks' of the video to fill the buffer and as you are paused it will not need to request any more once it is full.

One thing to be careful of is if your videos are live streams - then you probably actually may not want to resume from the paused point but from the current live point.

Comment: the videos are on loop, and its on our server.. so if i'm going to just pause it there will be 5 videos that is on pause and one on play, would that be better than? removing and adding them every time i switch the slider and just have one on play?

Comment: Serving videos from your own server (I assume you mean the same one that has your static and dynamic web content) is probably not going to scale to well so I am guessing your site is quite small and your traffic will be modest. In this case I think you will be fine, but you can try and do some timings if you are worried. If you really want to go for good performance you should consider serving your videos from a streaming server or hosted streaming service and using a CDN. It all depends on your traffic usages etc to decide if this is justified.

Comment: Hi Mick, thanks again for your response.. my videos are really small 2.2mb would be the biggest since they are just background videos for sugar coating purpose to the site. so everything would be fine right? cause my main concern is performance and smoothness of the site since this is just a onepage website with a lot of images.